# Symfony 4 - Getting 404 error when looking for URL on remote site

Tags: symfony

I have a local Symfony project that is running great, I have just however moved it over to the remote and run composer. Now it finds the "welcome screen" without an issue but If I then try and look for a controller using a URL I am getting 404 errors and all the controllers functions.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Have you cleared your production caches with the param `--env=prod` ?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with URL rewrite. Do you use apache or nginx? You might want to compare you configuration with the reference from [the documenation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

Comment: Can you determine if the 404 is thrown by you webserver or by your framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just in case anyone else has this issue, with Symfony 4 and Apache I need to run the following command

> composer require symfony/apache-pack

as stated here [Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)